# How to make an HTML table that has rows that drop down under category rows?

Tags: html, html-table

Hello I am trying to make an html table that looks like the one in the picture.

[image: Before and After Table]

The two columns are simply user on the left and score on the right. This is simple. What I don't know how to do is the transition between the left and the right table. In the table all users will fall under a team category. The team's score will be the users average score. When the table first loads I want all the teams to be collapsed like how they are on in the right table, but I want the user to be able to click on a team name and have it expand and drop down like the table on the left. Can some one please show the example code on how to do this? I have looked all over and right now the only solution I have is to make the table and have separate lists for each team. However this solution does not fully work since the user's score would not appear in the table's score column. So please can someone provide some example code?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thinking if it as one table perhaps think about it as a container with multiple sub containers and that the sub containers can be opened and closed. It can be styled however one likes, even to look like a table with alternating background color rows. You might need some js to reapply the alternating background colors if the sub containers sometimes have odd or even amounts of entries.

There are several plugins available to help with creating accordions. Like this one: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: ended up using accordion, but a non query based one